# How i can find homogeneity and enargy of image block

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, feature-extraction

Suppose I have block of pixels form an image as following

```
8  5  22 94 63 
65 98 52 41 32 
65 21 48 59 77  
20 14 15 63 52 
21 63 77 85 95
```

how can I find `homogeneity` and `energy`of these pixels (block)

and I tried to compute entropy for these values as following :

```
H=hist(block(:));
pro=H./25;
pro(pro==0)=[];            % remove zeros 
Ent=-sum(pro.*log2(pro));  %entropy equation
```

Is this correct way to calculate the entropy?

Comment: Which are the definitions you are using for them?

Comment: there are set of feature that extracted from `GLCM` `homo,energy, contrast` ,,  using a function `graycoprops()` >> but the equation of 'homogeneity ' and 'energy' I think used only for `GLCM` >> but when i apply same the equation  of homogeneity on an image block directly it's give me a good result(accuracy)  on my system <<<<<< note that I'm working on CBIR system >>>

Comment: I divide image into block and the `homo,energy` extracted from each block << and used to create a feature vector ,, and please what about the calculation of entropy in my question ?

Comment: Sorry, what is GLCM and CBIR?

Comment: GLCM => gray level co-occurrence matrix and CBIR refer to content based image retrieval